# (LUA) Is there a function or method to get the KEY from a table

Tags: lua, roblox

```lua
    {
    ["Question"] = "A stupid one";
    }
```

What is the best way to get the first key of a table?

I was thinking I could iterate through the loop, but surely there is a better method, or built-in function.

Thanks!

(This is my first time using StackOverflow so I apologise if I did anything wrong)

Comment: There is no notion of "the first key of a table" in Lua. `next` gives you *a* first key for traversal, but this key may change if the table changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to iterate to get key.

You can use `pairs` for any keys and `ipairs` for sequential integer keys starting from 1.

`pairs` uses `next` function which returns next key in the table but it can't be used to find specific key without iterating it.

To find a key for the value "A stupid one" use this:

```lua
for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if v == "A stupid one" then
       print("Key is:", k)
       break
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I hoped there was a built-in function but apparently not.

Comment: @Spar the `next` function mentioned in the answer _is_ the built in function to give you the first key in a table.

Comment: @Nifim Yes, I know, but if you have just a numeric sequence, please consider ipairs.
@Kylaaa Yes I am aware, i'm answering the question: there is no built-in function, `next` is similar but still requires iteration

Comment: Ooh oops, tagged the wrong person. Sorry! Meant to tag Alex101.